# Google sheets Query >= function not working

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I am trying to make a simple dashboard to get data from one sheet to show if it is greater than a week in cell B2

=QUERY('KPI 14 - 26'!A1:CC14,"select A, sum(F), sum(D), count(D)
where A is not null
AND A >= '"&B2&"'
group by A")

This code doesn't throw an error, but just doesn't display any date. If I change >- to contains it will show one weeks data. How can I fix this so that it shows all the data in weeks > week b2?

All of the data in column A on my data sheet are numbers (14 to 26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY('KPI 14 - 26'!A1:CC14,
 "select A,sum(F),sum(D),count(D) 
  where A is not null 
    and A >= "&B2*1&" 
  group by A")
```